# Jax-ws @PreDestroy When does it get called exactly?

Tags: java, annotations, jax-ws

I have a simply web service using `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestory` annotations.

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {...} //initialize some database connection

@PreDestroy
private void release() {...} //release data base resources
```

then a client will call some web methods to do some database operations. I did a simply testing by setting break points in the code. The `@PostConstruct` works fine. but `@PreDestroy` method never get called.

I thought `@PreDestroy` will always get called when a client finish calling a web method since web service is stateless by nature. So in the end, the instance is always destroyed and before that, my release method should be called? Is this a correct understanding?

But after reading some online resources, i got confused. some says `@PreDestroy` will be called when it's un-deployed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@PreDestroy` is only called when the application server decides to reduce the size of the Method-Ready pool - i.e. it determines it doesn't need to keep as many instances of your `@WebService @Stateless` session bean around.  It doesn't get called after each invocation of your `@WebMethod` (and `@PostConstruct` is only called when a new instance is added to the Method-ready pool, not necessarily before each web method invocation).

If you have logic you need called before and after each method invocation you could do it as follows:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept( InvocationContext ctx )
{
  try
  {
    init();
    return ctx.proceed();
  }
  finally
  {
    release();
  }
}
```

This method can be added to your `@WebService` bean or as a separate class using `@Interceptors`

Comment: so does this mean I cannot even use @PostConstruct to init my database connection?

Comment: Not if you want it initialized before every web service method call.  It only gets called when the session bean is created and added to the pool.  Is there any reason why you aren't using JPA and injecting an EntityManager using the @PersistenceContext annotation?  It's better to have the container manage your database connections for you when possible.

Comment: I believe the `intercept` method signature should declare `throws Exception`.